# How to check for novelty effect in AB testing?

Tags: r, logistic, t-test, ab-test

I have a simulated ab testing result where the target variables is binary - purchase or not. And I have new and old as customer type. How do I check for the novelty effect? Can I break them into 2 dataset `data[customer_type=='new']` and `data[customer_type=='old']` then run t test on each of them to check the p-value?

Answer (score 1):

Dichotomization is not an efficient way to deal with data.  Do we really think that people who are "old" customers less a day are different than "old" customers plus a day?  Probably not.

One way to deal with this is to adjust for customer tenure (in days, for example).  In the case the distribution of tenure is long tailed (for example, there are very few customers with very long tenure), you can curb the influence of outlying customers by log transforming the tenure variable.  You can add additional flexibility into the model by using splines to model the effect of tenure, which -- should it exist -- will better enable you to detect "novelty" effects.

Comment: What you said make perfectly sense.However this is a school project with simulated test result and customer type (new vs old,no info available for tenure) is one of the variable in the data. Right now I am just wondering by splitting them into new and old then run logistic regression(measured metric is binary) on them separately is a reliable way to detect for novelty effect in this context?

Comment: @xiahfyj The answer is "no" then.  Analyze them jointly by including an indicator variable for new/old.

Comment: Think I am getting some conflicting info. Here is where I learn how to check for novelty effect:https://productds.com/wp-content/uploads/Novelty_Effect.html     .The teacher separates data into new customer and old then ttest them separately. So you are saying this is not the way to check for novelty effect?

Comment: @xiahfyj If your outcome is binary, and you have two other binary variables (test/control and new/old) a logistic regression with two indicator variables for each of the two categories is a better approach than splitting data into groups.  You're free to do what your teacher says and split them up into groups, but taken to the logical extreme data splitting in this fashion will quickly shrink groups to a point where power is too small.

Comment: Make sense! One last question: If I use logistic regression, what would be a better approach 1. leave the binary indicator for customer type as new and old 2. changes them into 1 and 0 3. One hot encoding so new is (0,1) old is (1,0). Is there any difference among them?

Comment: Use 0 as old, 1 as new.